# Target a sub element of an object for DataGrid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Let's say I want to build a `DataGrid` with an object like that

```
{
  first: "firstValue",
  second: "secondValue",
  sub: {
    firstSub: "value",
    secondSub: "value
  }
}
```

How can I declare the columns to have a column for both `firstSub` and `secondSub`? I've tried things like

```
const columns = [
  ...
  { field: 'first', headerName: 'First', width: 70 },
  { field: 'sub.firstSub', headerName: 'Sub One', width: 70 },
  { field: 'sub.secondSub', headerName: 'Sub Two', width: 130 },
  ...
];
```

or

```
const columns = [
  ...
  { field: 'first', headerName: 'First', width: 70 },
  { field: 'sub/firstSub', headerName: 'Sub One', width: 70 },
  { field: 'sub/secondSub', headerName: 'Sub Two', width: 130 },
  ...
];
```

But I did not manage to find a working way.

Comment: It seems `fileld` doesn't support the nested data structure. Maybe you should flat the `sub` of initial object first.